# How to join two operations to create a new operation in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following two operations that I'm repeating multiple times:

```
  x = Conv3D(2*feature_size, 3, activation="relu", padding="same", strides=2)(x)
  x = BatchNormalization()(x)
```

```
  x = Conv3D(2*feature_size, 3, activation="relu", padding="same", strides=2)(x)
  x = BatchNormalization()(x)
  x = Conv3D(2*feature_size, 3, activation="relu", padding="same", strides=2)(x)
  x = BatchNormalization()(x)
  x = Conv3D(2*feature_size, 3, activation="relu", padding="same", strides=2)(x)
  x = BatchNormalization()(x)
  x = Conv3D(2*feature_size, 3, activation="relu", padding="same", strides=2)(x)
  x = BatchNormalization()(x)
  x = Conv3D(2*feature_size, 3, activation="relu", padding="same", strides=2)(x)
  x = BatchNormalization()(x)
```

And I want to create a new Tensorflow operations that joins the two operations into a single operation, with the name Conv3D_bnorm, so that it can be used like:

```
x = Conv3D_bnorm(2*feature_size, 3, activation="relu", padding="same", strides=2)(x)
```

BatchNormalization need not have custom parameters.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define a function, for example:

```
def Conv3D_bnorm(x, feature_size):
    conv = Conv3D(2*feature_size, 3, activation="relu", padding="same", strides=2)
    bn = BatchNormalization()
    
    return bn(conv(x))
```

BUT more logical is to use a keras's [Sequential](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential) module:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = ...

Conv3D_bnorm = tf.keras.Sequential()
Conv3D_bnorm.add(Conv3D(2*feature_size, 3, activation="relu", padding="same", strides=2))
Conv3D_bnorm.add(BatchNormalization())

x = Conv3D_bnorm(x)
```

Comment: Wouldn't the first example give "x" not defined?

Comment: @zendevil Depends on the usage. Anyway you can add the `x` as a parameter to this function.